# SNMP MIB Table complex data object

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, asn.1, mib

Can a table entry include a complex data object? For example can a table entry look like this?

```
ExampleTableEntry ::=
    SEQUENCE {
        simpleDataObject1         INTEGER,
        complexDataObject2        ComplexType,
        SimpleDataObject3         TruthValue
    }

ComplexType  OBJECT-IDENTITY    
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
      " What ever "
    ::= { parent 1 }

subObject1 OBJECT-TYPE                        
    SYNTAX   DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
    MAX-ACCESS  read-create
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
            " Diameter peer's host name. Reference: RFC 3588 "
    ::= { ComplexType 1 }

subObject2 OBJECT-TYPE                       
    SYNTAX   Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-create
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
            "  "
    ::= { ComplexType 2 }
```

Can the ComplexType be defined through a Textual convention or as an Object Identity?
Object Group?

If not, am I forced to add the sub objects to the parent table entry?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

This is something strictly defined in SNMP RFC documents, such as

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#page-25

As the `<syntax>` part must be of `SYNTAX` clause format, it cannot be the thing you imagined.

In your case, you either define more objects in the sequence, or write a secondary table to accompany.

Comment: You have pointed me to documentation that confirms what I thought was the answer. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Very good!